# Spring @RequestParams combined with LDAP Queries

Tags: java, spring, ldap

i have a little Rest-Application with a method to get all all users from the LDAP.
The spring method looks like that:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public List<User> getUsers(@RequestParam(
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "start") Long start,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "sort") String sort,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "asc") boolean asc)
        throws Exception {

    LdapContext ctx= .....
    List<User> Users;

    try {
        Users = searchUsers(ctx, "ou=users", start, sort, asc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ....
    } finally {
        ctx.close();
    }
    return Users;
}
```

And the method for searching all users is:

```
private List<User> searchUsers(LdapContext ctx, String ou, Long start, 
            String sort, boolean asc) throws Exception {

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> enumResult = null;
        List<User> LdapUserList = null;
        int totalSize = 0;

        try {
            SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
            searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            searchCtrls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);

            // Create a sort control that sorts based on sort-field
            String sortKey = sort;
            ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[] { new SortControl(sortKey, false) });

            String filter = "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))";

            enumResult = ctx.search(ou, filter, searchCtrls);


            // Iterate over sorted search results
            while (enumResult != null && enumResult.hasMore()) {

                totalSize++;                
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) enumResult.next();
                System.out.println("Result: "+result.getName());

                User ldapUser = new User(); 

                ldapUser.add(......)
                // some code to fullfil the ldapUser with attributes

                UserList.addElement(ldapUser);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ....
        }

        System.out.println(totalSize);
        return UserList;

    }
```

I tried to call my spring application via the link "/users?sort=uid" now.

The problem is, that i get all user from my ou, but they are not sorted. 
If i print out the variable "sort", i get the right "uid". So the @RequestParam is also working.
How can i can sort the results of my ldap response on server side? Where is the mistake?

Finally and later i want to add more param like in the code "asc" and "start" for sorting order and the start-index.

Thank you for every help!

Comment: The Spring Data project has LDAP extensions that might save you having to write a lot of boiler plate. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/ldap/docs/1.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#ldap.repositories

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Because i work here and in a lot of other functions with context (ctx) and searchResult, etc. i want to use the filter and RequestControls.
Then i will continue searching, thanks!